Angular Error with Custom Data fields on Relationships
This error is similar to one I asked about earlier this week in a ticket about FormBuilder, but I came into it from a completely different direction, and I confirmed that the problem exists on a Demo site.
If there is a custom field group related to Relationships, if someone searches for data in that custom field group, it results in a
TypeError: apiResults is undefined

I created the custom field group on The d10-master.demo.civicrm.org site. It will probably be refreshed by the time anyone looks at it, but here is the search I made to access that data in SearchKit:
https://d10-master.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Contact?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22id%22,%22sort_name%22,%22contact_type:label%22,%22contact_sub_type:label%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5B%22Contact%20AS%20Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01%22,%22INNER%22,%22RelationshipCache%22,%5B%22id%22,%22%3D%22,%22Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01.far_contact_id%22%5D,%5B%22Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01.near_relation:name%22,%22%3D%22,%22%5C%22Child%20of%5C%22%22%5D,%5B%22Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01.relationship_test.test_relationship_field%22,%22%3D%22,%22%5C%22true%5C%22%22%5D%5D%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D

Same Search in the SearchKit Query Info tab:
{
  "version": 4,
  "select": [
    "id",
    "sort_name",
    "contact_type:label",
    "contact_sub_type:label"
  ],
  "orderBy": {},
  "where": [],
  "groupBy": [],
  "join": [
    [
      "Contact AS Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01",
      "INNER",
      "RelationshipCache",
      [
        "id",
        "=",
        "Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01.far_contact_id"
      ],
      [
        "Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01.near_relation:name",
        "=",
        "\"Child of\""
      ],
      [
        "Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01.relationship_test.test_relationship_field",
        "=",
        "\"true\""
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "having": []
}

The search fails, with this in the console:
TypeError: apiResults is undefined
    controller https://d10-master.demo.civicrm.org/libraries/civicrm/core/ext/search_kit/ang/crmSearchAdmin/resultsTable/crmSearchAdminResultsTable.component.js?r=N2j7oen_US:50
    runSearch https://d10-master.demo.civicrm.org/libraries/civicrm/core/ext/search_kit/ang/crmSearchDisplay/traits/searchDisplayBaseTrait.service.js?r=N2j7oen_US:192
    Lodash 2
        qt
        Re
    runSearch https://d10-master.demo.civicrm.org/libraries/civicrm/core/ext/search_kit/ang/crmSearchDisplay/traits/searchDisplayBaseTrait.service.js?r=N2j7oen_US:191
    Angular 6
        processQueue
        scheduleProcessQueue
        $digest
        evalAsync
        completeTask
        timeoutId
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {} angular.js:15697:41
    Angular 7
        consoleLog
        get
        processChecks
        $digest
        evalAsync
        completeTask
        timeoutId

